# Use Math.Pow and keep the sign?

Tags: c#, pow

Is there anyway I can do this without using ifs?

Like I want to do `Math.Pow(-5f,2f)` to come out as -25 not 25?

Comment: Why do you expect it to be -25? It is (Sqr of -5) supposed to be 25.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about with [`Math.Sign`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z394hhsx.aspx):

> Returns a value indicating the sign of a single-precision
>   floating-point number.

So the computation would be:

```
Math.Sign(x) * Math.Pow(x, y)
```

If the idea is to always use the sign of the first operand  *even* when the `Pow` operation returns a negative value (instead of just negating the result when the first operand is negative), you can do:

```
Math.Sign(x) * Math.Abs(Math.Pow(x, y))
```

Comment: x is negative & y is odd would lose the sign

Comment: @Austin: Ok, I've addressed that assuming that's what the OP wants. It's not clear either way.